# iOS 14 Default user interface style

Tags: swift, xcode, plist, ios14

It seems that Xcode 12 is no longer supporting a default user interface style provided in the info.plist for iOS14. Is this a bug with the beta or is there any other way to provide this information without the need of overwriting every single element?

Answer (score 1):

The following code did the trick

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
        
        window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
```

Comment: I don’t think that’s right. Some of those windows don’t belong to you.

Comment: I added the code to the first viewControllers viewDidLoad and it works fine through the whole application